# Nothing human is foreign to me

Tags: reference-request

I've been reading this great book 'Love Yourself As If Your Life Depends On It' by Kamal Ravikant. Absolute great book, changing my life right now even. Whenever I come across this quote, it always puzzles me as to what its meaning is.

It has many forms yet the form recited in this book is 'I am human therefore nothing human is foreign to me'.

Any thoughts as to the meaning of this quote? I realise this may not be the best place to ask this question. Yet any light you can shed on it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [Terence (195/185 – ca. 159 BC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence) : One famous quotation by Terence reads: "Homo sum, humani nihil a me alienum puto", or "I am human, and I think nothing human is alien to me."

Comment: We can comment Kamal Ravikant's "discovery" with another quote : ["nothing new under the sun (*Ecclesiate*)](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nothing-new-under-the-sun).

Comment: Good question. I don't think it should be closed. This quote appears with some frequency in Western philosophical works.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of the quote about love is explained at length by Paul Ferrini in his book 'Unconditional Love'. I highly recommend it. He also explains the second quote, by reference to the shared identity of all human beings.

This is Christianity in its non-dual form, a.k.a. the 'mystical' theology, by which it is a strand of the Perennial philosophy. For a more detailed discussion than Ferrini there is 'A Course in Miracles'.